# Calculating $\int \frac{1}{a^2+x^2} dx $ using substitution method

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I know that:

$$
\int \frac{1}{a^2+x^2} dx = \frac{1}{a}arctan \frac{x}{a} + C
$$

So i tried:

$$
\frac{1}{a^2(1+(x/a)^2)} = \frac{1}{a^2}\frac{1}{(1+(x/a)^2)}
$$

$$t = (1+(x/a)^2) \Rightarrow dt = \frac{2x}{a^2}dx \Rightarrow 2xdx = a^2dt$$

Now what can i do?

I know that there is a strait way to solve cuz $\int \frac{1}{1+x^2} = arctanx + C$

But why the substitution doesnt work for me?

Thanks.

Comment: Let $t=\frac{x}{a}$. Now try $dt$ and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Try with $t = x /a$ so that

$$
{\rm d}t = \frac{{\rm d}x}{a}
$$

and your integral becomes

$$
\int \frac{{\rm d}x}{a^2 + x^2} = \frac{1}{a}\int \frac{{\rm d}(x/a)}{1 + (x/a)^2} = \frac{1}{a} \int \frac{{\rm d}t}{1 + t^2} = \cdots
$$

Answer (score 1):

So, we know

$$\int \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx = \arctan(x)+C$$

We thus want to manipulate the integral into a form like this. Let's begin with how you did it, factoring out $a^2$:

$$\mathcal I = \int \frac{1}{a^2+x^2} dx = \frac{1}{a^2} \int \frac{1}{1+(x/a)^2}dx$$

Now just let $u=x/a$. (Doing this will get us a $1+u^2$ form in the denominator, which is ideal, so this is the right substitution.) Then $du=dx/a \implies dx = a \cdot du$. Then

$$\mathcal I = \frac{1}{a^2} \int \frac{a}{1+u^2}du = \frac 1 a \int \frac{1}{1+u^2}du$$

You can continue from here to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Try the substitution $x=a\tan (t)$

Then $\mathrm dx=a\sec^2 (t) \mathrm dt$

And the entire integral changes to:

> $I=\displaystyle \int \dfrac{a\sec^2(t)}{a^2(1+\tan^2 (t))} \mathrm dt$
>
>  $=\displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{a} \mathrm dt=\dfrac{t}{a}+C$
>
>  Then from the substitution obtain the value of $t=\tan^{-1} \dfrac{x}{a}$